# Unable to to create media player

Tags: android, android-video-player

While trying to play video using media player, I am getting this error:

```
Unable to to create media player
D/MediaPlayer(13157): create failed:
D/MediaPlayer(13157): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
```

Can any one suggest here what's the problem?

Comment: The FileDescriptor that you provide is invalid ?

Comment: can u please provide me more detail about filedescriptor...what u mean to say this?

Comment: Please paste the code you use to initialize the player

Comment: always remember to add code sample thats actually giving you error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@onsurfaceCreate` 
using following code to play video, now here I thinking problem is bit different,because same code is working for low resolution video but for high resolution video it prompt me error..."

```
 holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
 R.raw.livewallpaper);          mediaPlayer.setDisplay(new
 VideoSurfaceHolder(holder));   

    mediaPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getAssets().openFd(mediaElementArray.getInteger.valueOf(index)));

myMediaplayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
```

this one works.. actually in assets folder what ever you store is saved as one large compressed chunk , so you need to assign `afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength()`

also. as it will tell what from where the source u r requesting for starts and whats the length of it, which helps it to calculate the valid requested file in that large chunk.

Or the other reason can be .. the file you are referencing is not of correct format or might be corrupt

Comment: this way is also useful when using APK extension files to play video from since `ZipResourceFile`'s `getAssetFileDescriptor()` returns `AssetFileDescriptor`.